# How to read an environment variable from a Chapel program?

Tags: environment-variables, chapel

How can one read an environment variable within a Chapel program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Environment variables can be accessed through the C interface by calling [`getenv`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html), e.g.

```
// Compiled and run on Chapel 1.22.0

extern proc getenv(name : c_string) : c_string;

var value = getenv('SOME_ENV_VAR'.c_str()):string;
```

Anyone may try, test & extend this code *[online](https://tio.run/##vVNdb9owFH3Pr7iKNJWwYlO2l4H6wMDtItGkIikbT5YJhlhK7Mg2dN2fZ06AFZ7WD6lXiuwk9/qcc@9xlrOKF7sdbsMovrsPJ2QKN5PhbdKHTmfLtRFKegCQ5VUBh3e4Qr0u6tafR6p60mKdW2hlAfS63a@dXvfq2yWMNHuCUGYIoJVwDpNwRKKEwEoUHFZKQ6k0hyW3TBQmgDb2PIxBlJXSFmZ7nAFgjF4b4O8P8QGSeZQOf4FUFtjW4bCFw17wVY08anTXSr58rpE3hjs570Q@VPtwF48fJuRVyERuB/X6NmRX7TfVL0Z2uQfkMEY3SpfMWr4M40E9CPT@qL1RVm7aS2ByCXojwTnnmULPGcjjvy3XEiqtMlhzy@W2JVnJoQ8ZNVYLuQ5O9o7almnYsmLD4fpYcPGQkOkFapJaQdD/l4uxsLyQLfDTXBj4OUwgO1LaGJcDn4yPVo30VmPww/wggODoAPBPfvjujkRJ@oLuPuoz7B8O23EVWsmSSws15etT9L2mGtfD7UPpe8YAfqEyVnDkmtR4434aj/7PG9zFZEtVOSeAsjnXj8JwD46xF3M3nIPmrJ7rmaghTR6mhKYxjeKU/hjOCP1OSETH5CaMyJjOSUpJNKNJOg2j2zP5Z2Rd0153lH/5TPGjwp9zQ61rxwkPmjNDXY/pgnNJDbf0yT1hNCZk7GbifzxLCLyPxQgGb7ctTPkK9SG3tjJ9jDWrxJ8rtBY23yyQUDhrjNpxlpsxLWoLG1yq5aZejc6wsw7KbVk4Om282/0F)*.

For more environment variable APIs, see the user-developed [EnvVariables module](https://github.com/Rapiz1/chapel-envVariables).

Comment: For a distributed memory execution of a Chapel program, could it be the case that different results would occur on different locales?  And is this a capability that ought to be raised to an official library capability rather than relying on extern declarations and types?

Comment: @Brad - Yes. This is managed more cleanly in the EnvVariables module linked in the answer (the interface is tied to a locale, e.g. `locale.getEnv()`). See https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues/5939 for related design discussions.

Comment: @ben-albrecht Given the nature of heterogeneous NUMA code-execution environments, how well does the distributed "environment" distribute (at least to reflect) the environment settings "across" such wild landscape of all non-local locales? In other words, does the abstracted "environment" retain its role & functions (to *set/hold* & *retain/get* & *modify/(re)propagate update(s)* ) homogeneously across all non-local locales, or has the "environment" already lost both its meaning and role, as the distributed nature of the heterogeneous NUMA ecosystem has no such uniform "environment" possible?

Comment: @user3666197 - I believe all locales will inherit the environment from the shell session that launches the program when using the default launcher for multilocale Chapel programs. Once the program is running, modifications to the environment will be on a per-locale basis. Any form of synchronized updates across locales would require additional effort. The code example in my answer is intentionally minimal. For a more robust implementation, I suggest checking out the EnvVariables module linked above. Further discussion might be more relevant as a design issue over there as well.